# I can't find a table using bs4, and I found an alternative using `re`, but I'm not sure how to get the information I need

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-re

I wanted to create a dictionary where I would pull the `holdings` as the key along with the `Weight(%)` as the value. But when I try to use `soup.find('table', {'id' : 'etf_holding_table'})`  to access the table, nothing shows up. I saw some posts saying that it might be inside a comment and tried to copy a few ways things were done there, but I wasn't able to do so successfully.

I ended up finding someone's response to a way to pull ticker information using `re`, but I can't seem to find any good resources explaining what his code was doing.
[Here is the post I copied code from to get the ticker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64908086/using-python-to-identify-etf-holdings).

```py
import requests
import re

keys = ['ARKK']
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0"}
url = 'https://www.zacks.com/funds/etf/ARKK/holding'

with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        for key in keys:
            r = req.get(url.format(key))
            goal = re.findall(r'etf\\\/(.*?)\\', r.text)
            print(goal)
```

```
OUTPUT
['TSLA', 'TDOC', 'COIN', 'ROKU', 'U', 'ZM', 'SPOT', 'SQ', 'SHOP', 'PATH', 'TWLO', 'EXAS', 'NTLA', 'Z', 'PLTR', 'CRSP', 'TWTR', 'BEAM', 'DKNG', 'NVTA', 'FATE', 'TXG', 'DOCU', 'HOOD', 'PACB', 'PD', 'IRDM', 'TSP', 'DNA', 'TWST', 'VCYT', 'SGFY', 'SKLZ', 'EDIT', 'TWOU', 'IOVA', 'SSYS', 'TRMB', 'BLI', 'MTLS', 'CERS', 'CGEN', 'PRLB', 'NSTG']
```

By playing around a little with the `re.findall()` I was sort of able to get the information I wanted (highlighted in yellow), but I'm not sure how to get the numbers I need now.
[image: messing around]

I'd very much appreciate some good resources on understanding and using `re` as I clearly don't understand too well what I'm doing, or how to get the information I need. I would message the poster I got the code from, but it seems as though you can't message someone on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is contained inside a "javascript variable" `etf_holdings.formatted_data`

```
<script>
var etf_holdings            = {};
etf_holdings.formatted_data = [ [ "TESLA INC", ...
```

This is processed by javascript in your browswer and turned into the table you see.

When you fetch the raw html with `requests` - you're not executing javascript - which is why the table is "not there" when you try to find it with BeautifulSoup.

One way of isolating the line containing the data:

```
>>> import json, requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://www.zacks.com/funds/etf/ARKK/holding', headers={'User-Agent': ''})
>>> line = next(line for line in r.text.splitlines() if line.startswith('etf_holdings.formatted_data '))
```

If we keep the `[ [ .... ] ]` i.e. remove everything before the first `=`  and chop off the trailing semicolon - we can load this using the `json` module.

```
>>> line[:40]
'etf_holdings.formatted_data = [ [ "TESLA'
>>> line[-10:]
'</a>" ] ];'
```

`.find()` and slicing is one way to do this:

```
>>> line = line[line.find('= ') + 2:-1]
>>> data = json.loads(line)
>>> len(data)
45
```

Each item is the raw data used to create a row in table:

```
>>> data[0]
['TESLA INC',
 '<button class="modal_external appear-on-focus" 
    href="/modals/quick-quote.php" rel="TSLA">TSLA Quick Quote</button>
    <a href="//www.zacks.com/funds/etf/TSLA" rel="TSLA" 
    class=" hoverquote-container-od " show-add-portfolio="true" >
    <span class="hoverquote-symbol">TSLA<span class="sr-only"></span></span></a>',
 '2,073,604',
 '11.18',
 '8.48',
 '<a class="report_document newwin" 
   href="/zer/report/TSLA" alt="View Report" title="View Report"></a>']
```

Comment: I see! this is making more sense now as I was not sure why there was an `etf` in the `re.find()`. This is slowly starting to make more sense and thanks for your explanation Karl!

Answer (score 1):

So, as already pointed out, the data is within a different JavaScript variable within the response.

I would therefore alter the regex to pick up that entire JavaScript array object, then pass that to json library to extract the desired info.

The regex would be:

`etf_holdings\.formatted_data = (\[.*?\]);`

That is matching as follows:

[image]

Compile this pattern in advance for efficiency of re-use.

Use `.search()` to match anywhere in string then extract the first match group.

Parse the extracted group with json and you get a list of lists as follows:

[image]

Note that the data you want is contained at indices 1 and 3 of each list within the parent list. Index 1 is html you can parse with BeautifulSoup to get the desired symbol, and index 3 can be directly extracted. For some items there is no symbol/associated weight value:

[image]

As this could lead to the same key being parsed out during scraping, with no meaning in final dictionary, I simply exclude these items by testing whether `rel="` is present in index 1 string. This is to avoid parsing twice the html within the list comprehension.

I make an assumption - based on examining the aforementioned index 1 strings, and that these are highly specific short strings - that this is sufficient to accurately determine the presence/absence of the symbol. If present, I create a BeautifulSoup object from index 1 and then extract the first `rel` attribute to get the symbol. I pair that with the index 3 value , in a tuple within the list comprehension, to end up with a list of tuples. I extend a global list with that returned list of tuples, each time through the loop over the global list `keys`.

Finally, I convert that list of tuples to a dictionary. This assumes that there are not repeated symbols across different requests. If there can be repeated potential keys within the global list of tuples you will need to amend the logic to capture the parent ETF and then decide how to handle.

```
import re
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        for key in keys:
            r = req.get(url.format(key))
            print(f"Extracting: {r.url}")
            data = json.loads(re_object.search(r.text).group(1))
            values.extend([(bs(i[1], 'lxml').select_one('[rel]')['rel'], i[3])
                          for i in data if ' rel="' in i[1]])


keys = ['ARKK', 'VPOP']
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
values = []
re_object = re.compile(r'etf_holdings\.formatted_data = (\[.*?\]);')

main("https://www.zacks.com/funds/etf/{}/holding")
ticker_weights = dict(values)
print(ticker_weights)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Qharr! I spent a good amount of time looking over what you said alongside what Karl posted and I think it's all finally starting to click together! I probably spent around 3 hours just going back and forth playing around to try to fully understand what you're saying and get what everything in the code is doing.  Thanks again Qharr! :)